# Class to sorting generic list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have simply class to sorting generic List. I am doing it by using quicksort. Could you tell me why it doesn't work? (There is no any answer, program is workina all time).

In main I have:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Sort");
    EnumerableAlgorithm.Sort<int>(l, (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
    Console.WriteLine("Sort");
    foreach (int i in l)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

I see only first "Sort". I have any idea why it doesn't work. But if I take function Quicksort before main and call then it in Sort as

```
Program.QuickSort<T>(list, comparison, 0, list.Count-1);
```

it is working. I will grateful for help. Thanks in advance. Below my class to sorting:

```
   public static class EnumerableAlgorithm
    {
        public static void Sort<T>(List<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
        {
            QuickSort<T>(list, comparison, 0, list.Count-1);
        }

        public static void QuickSort<T>(List<T> array, Comparison<T> comparison, int left, int right)
        {
            var i = left;
            var j = right;
            var pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
            while (i < j)
            {       
                while (comparison(array[i],pivot) < 0) i++;
                while (comparison(array[i], pivot) > 0) j--;
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    // swap
                    var tmp = array[i];
                    array[i++] = array[j];  // ++ and -- inside array braces for shorter code
                    array[j--] = tmp;
                }
                if (left < j) EnumerableAlgorithm.QuickSort(array,comparison, left, j);
                if (i < right) EnumerableAlgorithm.QuickSort(array, comparison, i, right);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that List<T> already has a Sort method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

> `while (comparison(array[i], pivot) > 0) j--;`

To

> `while (comparison(array[j], pivot) > 0) j--;`

(change [i] to [j])

Your code was going into endless loop